# SSRS 2016 report manager using m/d/y date parameter format in Chrome

Tags: ssrs, ssrs-2016

I've got a 2016 SSRS server, set up with UK regional settings.  When using Chrome, date parameter fields are using the US mm/dd/yyyy format instead of the expected UK dd/mm/yyyy:

[image: Chrome]

Edge and IE are fine:

[image: Edge]

The date picker itself works fine, and the reports run normally in all browsers.  All reports are set to use en-GB language, and this happens on all client systems I've tried it on.  As far as I can tell all the server region and local settings are correct.

Any thoughts on how I can get SSRS to use the correct format in Chrome?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm not sure if this will work for you but Chrome uses it own language configuration.

Go to:

```
Settings 
  Show Advanced Settings
    Languages
      Language and Input Settings
```

And then select the desired language. (English UK)

Comment: Ah, would you look at that - Chrome was using a US locale after all.  Problem sorted, thanks!
![Chrome languages](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8T2j2.png).

Comment: I m glad to help

Answer (score 3):

I had the same issue, only opposite.  The default for Chrome was English UK.  I set Chrome to use English United States, however, it didn't work.  I did eventually realize that you have to set the order of the Languages.  When I moved the English United States to position 1, it worked, an FYI.

Answer (score 1):

Following on from @McNets, the problem is how to educate all of the users.

I plan to create an SSRS report that will be posted on the root of the server. It will have one date parameter and the text of the report will describe what to do, with embedded images of the configuration changes (to be updated with subsequent versions of Chrome) Users can then compare their date picker with report and perform the test!